# How do I add a class to a list?

Tags: java, list, interface

I have a class SnakeCaseFormatter by which

```
class SnakeCaseFormatter implements TextFormatter { etc...
```

and

```
List<TextFormatter> formatter = new ArrayList<TextFormatter>();
```

when I use

```
formatter.add(SnakeCaseFormatter);
```

I get an error which says: "SnakeCaseFormatter cannot be resolved to a variable".

May I know how to correct this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. If you want to add classes, then the TYPE of your list is wrong (see the answer from noiaverbale). If you want to add instances of that class to your list, then you have to create these first (the answer by jeroen).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SnakeCaseFormatter` is the name of your class, i.e. a design for an object. To get an actual object, you need to instantiate it:

```
SnakeCaseFormatter myFormatter = new SnakeCaseFormatter();
```

You can then add this instance to your list:

```
formatter.add(myFormatter);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need a list of classes, not instances, you need to define your list as

```java
List<Class<? extends TextFormatter>> formatter = new ArrayList<>();
formatter.add(SnakeCaseFormatter.class);
```